# Ogre + Kinect + OpenNI

Tags: kinect, blender, openni, ogre

I'm developing a program where a user can move a human mesh taking joints from kinect sensor!
I started with Sinbad example, loading it into a project: everything works correctly!

Next step: 
 - open Sinbad.blend in Blender
 - take only the skeleton
 - build my own mesh and "attach" it to the skeleton

Problem: when i load MyMesh instead of  Sinbad.mesh, my mesh appear totally distorced and a lot of bones move in wrong way!

Is this the right approach to my problem?!